# is there any easier way to get the LI list number in one UL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have following html code:

```
<ul>
    <li>Text</li>  <!-- number:0; means first one-->
    <li>Text</li>  <!-- number:1; second one-->
    <li>Text</li>  <!-- number:2; third one-->
    <li>Text</li>  <!-- number:3 -->
    <li>Text</li>  <!-- number:4 -->
    <li>Text</li>  <!-- number:5 -->
</ul>
```

in my method, set a attribute `number` to every `li`

```
i = 0;
$('li').each(function()
    {
        $(this).attr('number',i);
        i++;
    });
```

using `$(this).attr('number')` to get its number;

**here is jsFiddle DEMO** **http://jsfiddle.net/8tpab84s/**, is working

but i think the method is complicated, if the `DOM li` be changed, i need to set the number attribute again.

is there a easier way to instead this method ? without set any attribute.

thanks for your response.

Comment: You should not use the attribute name `number`, since it may clash with an HTML attribute in some future version of HTML. There are better ways to store data in a DOM node. But here it is unclear how you intend to *use* the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `attr()` with a function as the second argument:

```
$('li').attr('number', function(_index) {
    return _index;
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/techfoobar/8tpab84s/4/

**Thanks** to user: NicoSantangelo - You can simply use the first argument of the callback function instead of `$(this).index()`

Comment: Isn't the index the first argument of `attr`?

Comment: @NicoSantangelo - Yes, that can be used as well. In fact using that will be even more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8tpab84s/5/)

```
 var i = 0;
    $('li').each(function(i)
        {
           alert(i);
        });
```

you can use if statement after that

```
      var i = 0;
        $('li').each(function(i)
            {
               if(i == 1){ // that mean the li number 2
                 // your code here
               }
            });
```

and to get number of all li just use

```
$('li').length;
```